# How can I use a client's IP Address for a request to another website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ip-address, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to build an web app, where a client logs in and wants to send some data to another website (for example he wants to upload a csv file that the application will read and send the read data to the other website).

The website does not have an official API which I can use and they block an IP Address if it is making too many requests.

So, my idea was to use the user's IP Address to send the request in his name so that the website will not block my app from making requests.

It is possible to do this from asp .net core mvc / asp.net mvc?

If not, what can I do to make this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use js on client side?

Comment: what do you mean "use the user's IP Address"...you want the remote server to think the request came from their IP address and not yours? apart from sounding like it has the potential to constitute some sort of illegal impersonation, depending on the local law enforcement, I would think this is something which happens at the TCP/IP level,  nothing you can control through code. So your server can't really do it. Maybe you can make an AJAX request from the browser instead, if the remote server accepts CORS requests. But if it's not an official API it's quite likely it won't

Comment: It sounds like your client is giving you some data to process, which you are then sending to the remote website in a different format? I don't know enough details to know if this is feasible, but how about instead your application simply processes the data, and sends it _back to the client_ in the needed format, and then the client will upload it onto this 3rd party website themselves? It's less slick and automated, but it gets round the IP blocking issue. It sounds like this 3rd party website doesn't want to accept automated uploads anyway, so you can easily explain that to your client.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. I would encourage you to actually read up on the TCP/IP protocol (HTTP, too, while you're at it, though it doesn't directly relate to this issue). Just like you would need to understand how something like iOS works before you could write apps for it, you should not how the underlying protocols of the Internet work, if you intend to write web apps.

In particular here, all communication over TCP/IP is by IP address. It is necessarily unique because the client/server needs to be able to "address" its packets there. Based on this, even if you *could* impersonate the user's IP address, the result would be the server sending its response *directly* to the user, instead of your server.

FWIW, there is a concept of "shared" IP addresses. For example, unless you have a dedicated IP from your ISP, you along with a lot of its other customers will appear as if you all have the IP address. IP addresses are traditionally limited. IPv6 is virtually limitless, but most everything still uses IPv4, which only exposes a range of ~4 trillion addresses. That may sound like a lot, until you realize that every single client needs a unique address. Just one person likely has a home computer, a work computer, a laptop, a smartphone and perhaps even a second business smartphone. Additionally they could have a range of other devices like a tablet, smart TV, connected thermostat, etc.  As a result, your ISP essentially proxies your request to the destination and it then receives the response and forwards it on to you. It uses its internal IP tables to route the response back to the internal IP that requested it. So, while it's technically possible for multiple clients/servers to share the same external IP, it is not the same as what you're talking about here.

Comment: 2^32 is 4 billion on the short scale or 4 milliards no long scale ^^